# How to send data to external service in chunks with SAP ICF?

Tags: http, chunks, sap-basis

I am currently trying to implement SAP Communication with NODEJS external Service, where SAP sends data via Internet Communication Framework (ICF).

I am able already to send data in plain format. However, I am interested in sending it via chunks.
So I setup those two headers:

```
CALL METHOD server->response->set_header_field
  EXPORTING
    name  = 'Transfer-Encoding'
    value = 'chunked'.

CALL METHOD server->response->set_header_field
  EXPORTING
    name  = 'Content-Type'
    value = 'text/plain'.
```

And I set response data as indicated in Wikipedia:
c_result = '4\r\nWiki\r\n5\r\npedia\r\nE\r\n in\r\n\r\nchunks.\r\n0\r\n\r\n'.
server->response->set_cdata( c_result ).

However, when I call it in GW Client, I get error: "HTTP Receive failed: connection to partner broken".

When I call it in my NodeJS external service, I get error:

```
{ Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) bytesParsed: 945, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE' }
```

Could you please help me to identify where the issue is?
I have some suspects:

1. Either SAP ICF does not support chunks at all
2. Either I do not setup response correctly
3. Either response text is being modified additionally in SAP response processing.
   Is there someone experienced, who could help?

Answer (score 1):

I realized in the end, the ICF uses HTTP 1.0, and [chunks were added in HTTP 1.1 and retired in HTTP 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Please let me know if I should delete the question.

Comment: The question and answer are useful for future visitors, maybe now that you found the answer, you may generalize the question a little bit so that future visitors can find your post more easily.